# React Native phone application: Hide callee's number from caller

Tags: react-native

I am working on a messaging application in react-native, and I want the messengers to be able to call the clients without letting that messenger see the client's phone number. How can this be done?

To be clear -- I'm trying to hide the number from the senders/initiators, not the recipients.

I currently use

```
 import RNImmediatePhoneCall from 'react-native-immediate-phone-call';
```

render:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={[styles.buttons,{backgroundColor: this.state.colorB}]}
    onPress={() => {
                 RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall('3125340000');
            }}
>
<Image style={styles.icon}
       source={this.state.imageIcon2}/>
```

I can make calls but the number is still in sight. I want it to hide

version:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.48.4",
```

Comment: @ken Hi, maybe I did not understand my English is not good.

What I want is that the number is acculturated.
only for messengers who use the application.
not for the users who receive the call

Comment: Short form: You can do this, but not from your React Native app alone -- you'll need a different component forwarding phone calls between the parties in question using a platform such as [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You cant change how the phone deals with calling people. You can only use what the API provides you with which is probably just something like "call this number". From then on the phone does its thing with no way for you to manipulate what happens.

You would have to call the person through a third-party service that calls the number and streams the call to your phone over the internet, bypassing all the apis provided but you will either have to create that service yourself (<s>which will probably not work due to legal issues</s>) or find some existing one.

Comment: What legal issues? Running an Asterisk server that forwards calls (without giving the initiator access to the phone number of the recipient) isn't exactly magic, or without precedent, or even uncommon. Look at how Lyft &c. forward calls between customers and drivers through numbers they own -- as I read it, that's basically what the OP wants to implement themselves.

Comment: I added that part as the use case seemed kind of shady but I didnt really know about any relevant laws hence the "probably". You're right, it might actually be ok.